# How come I cannot move items within my array more than once?

Tags: java, arrays, class, reference, null

I have constructed this array: Organism cells[][]; I fill the array with ants and doodlebugs (both classes inherit Organism), and leave most of the spots null to represent empty spots. Then I attempt to move all of the ants and doodlebugs. To move them, I first find an empty space for a target, then change the targeted cell to the Organism that needs to move. After that, I kill (set to null) the Organism at the x/y of where the moved Organism **was**. So if I was moving cell[1][1] and cell[2][2] was my target, I would: set cell[2][2] = cell[1][1] and then set cell[1][1] = null.

My problem is, after doing this process a second time, the code no longer moves the organisms. Although all the organisms move the first time, I need this process to be repeatable.

How can i fix this? Thank you for your help.

There is a lot of code but I was asked to post the important parts. Sorry if it is quite lengthy, I tried to simplify it.

**World Class:**

```
public class World {
private final int HEIGHT = 20;
private final int WIDTH = 20;
private Organism cells[][];       // (0,0) is considered the upper left corner
public static Random generator = new Random(1000L);  // Use of a Random generator lets us provide same 
                            // sequence of "random" numbers.  Consequently, the
                            // simulation will be identical each run, aiding debugging.
//public static Random generator = new Random(); // Once your program works properly, comment out the statement
                            // above, and uncomment this one.  This will make your program run differently
                            // every time you run it. 
/**
 * @param  x  horizontal grid coordinate
 * @param  y  vertical grid coordinate.
 * 
 * @return If (x,y) are not legal coords, returns null.  Else  returns value of the that cell.  
 * This will eiher be an Organism or null.
 */
public Organism getCell(int y, int x){
    if (x < 0 || x >= WIDTH || y < 0 || y >= HEIGHT){ 
        return null;
    }
    return cells[y][x];
}

/**
 * @param  x  horizontal grid coordinate
 * @param  y  vertical grid coordinate.
 * @param org Organism to place in the world
 */
public void setCell(int x, int y, Organism org){
    cells[y][x]=org;
}

/**
 * @param x  horizontal grid coordinate
 * @param y  vertical grid coordinate.
 * @return  Return false if cell at given coords is not empty, or if coordinates are
 * "off the grid."  Else return true.
 */
public boolean isEmptyCell(int y, int x){
    // YOUR CODE HERE...
    if(getCell(y,x) != null){
        return false;
    }
    return true; 
}



/**
 * Construct a World.
 * If you don't want repeatable simulations (i.e., you want each to be unique),
 * remove the "seed" value from the Random() constructor.
 * @param numAnts  The number of Ants to place randomly in the grid.
 * @param numDoodles The number of Doodlebuggs to place randomly in the grid.
 */
public World(int numAnts, int numDoodles){
    int x=0, y=0, count1=0, count2=0;

    cells = new Organism[getHEIGHT()][getWIDTH()];

    // YOUR CODE HERE to randomly place ants and doodlebugs.
    while(count1<numAnts){
        y = myRand(getHEIGHT());
        x = myRand(WIDTH);
        if(isEmptyCell(y,x)){
            cells[y][x] = new Ant(y,x,this);
            count1++;
            //System.out.println("MAKING ANT at x=" + x +" and y= " + y);
        }
    }

    while(count2<numDoodles){
        y = myRand(getHEIGHT());
        x = myRand(WIDTH);
        if(isEmptyCell(y,x)){
            cells[y][x] = new Doodlebug(y,x,this);
            count2++;
        }
    }
}


/**
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @param org
 * @return  Return true if a new organism was added to the World, else return false.
 * If at least one of the adjacent cells to [x,y] is empty, randomly select one of the 
 * empty ones and place org there.  
 * [You might do this by first checking if there's at least one empty adjacent cell.
 * If so, use a loop to successively randomly select an adjacent cell until you find 
 * an empty one, then place org there.]
 *
 * [Oh, and this might be a good place to use a "switch" statement to deal with the 
 * four possible directions N,S,E,W.]
 */
public boolean addAdjacent(int x, int y, Organism org) {
    // YOUR CODE HERE....

    System.out.println("World.addAdjacent() not yet implemented.\n");
    return true; // MODIFY SO RETURNS TRUE ONLY WHEN APPROPRIATE
}

/**
 * Move all the ants.
 */
public void moveAllAnts() {
    clearAntFlags();
    for(int y=0; y<cells.length; y++){
        for(int x=0; x<cells[y].length;x++){
            if (getCell(x,y) instanceof Ant){
                //System.out.println("Ant found at: y=" + x + " and x="+ y +"\t\tmoved?   " + getCell(x,y).hasMoved);
                getCell(x,y).move();
            }
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Move all the doodlebugs.
 */
public void moveAllDoodles() {
    clearDoodleFlags();
    for(int y=0; y<cells.length; y++){
        for(int x=0; x<cells[y].length;x++){
            if (getCell(x,y) instanceof Doodlebug){
                //System.out.println("Doodle found at: y=" + x + " and x="+ y);
                getCell(x,y).move();
            }
        }
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    World w;
    w= new World(10,10);
    System.out.println("A thinly populated world:\n"+w);
    w.moveAllAnts();
    w.moveAllDoodles();
    System.out.println("A thinly populated world:\n"+w);
}

public int getHEIGHT() {
    return HEIGHT;
}

public int getWIDTH() {
    return WIDTH;
}


/**
 * @param x,y takes the location of the ant and attempts to find an adjacent empty cell.
 * @return  Return a point if an adjacent cell is empty, otherwise return null.
 */
public Point getAdjaEmpty(int y, int x){
    Point p = new Point(0,0);
    boolean up = false, down = false, left = false, right = false;
    int numTrue = 0;
    if(isEmptyCell(y-1,x) && y-1>=0){ // can go left
        left = true;
        numTrue++;
    }
    if(isEmptyCell(y+1,x) && y+1<cells.length){ // can go right 
        right = true;
        numTrue++;
    }
    if(isEmptyCell(y,x-1) && x-1>=0){ // can go up 
        up = true;
        numTrue++;
    }
    if(isEmptyCell(y,x+1) && x+1<cells[0].length){ // can go down 
        down = true;
        numTrue++;
    }

    if(numTrue >0){
        if(numTrue==1){
            if(left){
                p.x = x;
                p.y= y-1;
            }else if(right){
                p.x = x;
                p.y= y+1;
            }else if(up){
                p.x = x-1;
                p.y= y-1;
            }else if(down){
                p.x = x+1;
                p.y= y;
            }else{
                System.err.println("Error in adjacEmpty function!");
            }
        }else if(numTrue>=2){
            //make direction random
            int dir = 0;
            while(true){ //looks for a random spot that is empty and accessible
                dir = generator.nextInt(4);
                if(left && dir == 0){
                    p.x = x;
                    p.y= y-1;
                    //System.out.println("left"); 
                    break;
                }else if(right && dir == 1){
                    p.x = x;
                    p.y= y+1;
                    //System.out.println("right");
                    break;
                }else if(up && dir == 2){
                    p.x = x-1;
                    p.y= y;
                    //System.out.println("up"); 
                    break;
                }else if(down && dir == 3){
                    p.x = x+1;
                    p.y= y;
                    //System.out.println("down");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        return null;
    }
    return p;
}


/* Moves the Organism to the random location given by getAdjaEmpty
 * Also kills the old organism.
 * 
 */
public void killAndMove(int y, int x) {
    Point p = getAdjaEmpty(y,x);
    if(cells[y][x] != null){
        setCell(p.x,p.y, getCell(y,x));
        cells[y][x].kill();
    }
}
```

}

**Organism Class:**

```
abstract public class Organism {
protected int locX, locY;           // Coords of organism in its World.
protected boolean hasMoved;         // Movement flag: true if has already moved this turn [Can you see why this is needed?]
abstract public void move();        // Move the critter to an adjacent space
protected World myMap;              // Need this so each organism has access to its World.

/**
 * As this is an abstract class, this constructor is invoked via super() by its
 * subclasses.  Takes care of initializing the fields they inherit from this class.
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @param m
 */
public Organism(int x, int y, World m) {
// Initialize instance variables, including
    myMap = m;
    locX = x;
    locY = y;
    // YOUR CODE HERE!  What other instance variables?
}

/**
 * Clear the move flag.
 */
public void clearMoveFlag() {
    hasMoved = false;
}

/**
 * Remove the organism from the world.
 */
public void kill() {
    myMap.setCell(locY, locX, null);
}

/**
 * Choose a random direction.  If that cell is empty, move there.
 * Make sure to set the movement flag so there is no possibility of moving the
 * same organism again this turn.  
 * @see clearMoveFlag
 */
public void moveToEmpty() {
    // Remember to avoid moving a critter that has already moved this turn....
    // If you want a random number to choose a direction, try
    // int dir = World.myRand(4);
    //  to generate an integer 0-3.

    // YOUR CODE HERE!
    if(!hasMoved){
        myMap.killAndMove(locX, locY);
        //System.out.println("LocX = " +locX + " and locY = " + locY);
        hasMoved = true;
    }

}
/**
 * Set the location of the organism to the given coordinates.
 * @param x
 * @param y
 */
public void setLoc(int x, int y){
    locX = x;
    locY = y;
}

/**
 * @return Return a single character representing the organism.  To be 
 * used in constructing the printed representation of a World.
 */
public abstract String singleCharRepresenting();
```

}

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Often the problem is in your code not your algorithm, what makes sense on paper can be translated into code poorly.

Show us your code.

Comment: I added some snippets, I would post all of my code, but it is a lot. Last time I did something like that, I was told not to have so much code. If you have specific questions, I can always post more snippets.

Comment: (1) Make a copy of your program. (2) Start removing code that is not related to the problem, until you have a minimal program, maybe 20-30 lines, that still illustrates the problem. (3) Chances are you will now find the problem yourself since you've narrowed the scope, but if you still can't find it, you now have something reasonable to post here for us to help.

Comment: Where do you update `locY` and `locX`?

Comment: Posted most of the code. Sorry it's so long, I really tried to shorten it.

Comment: Yea, it's still stumping me.